# Best Approach for Push Notifications for both IOS and Android

Tags: react-native, asp.net-web-api, push-notification, azure-notificationhub

I am building the backend for our company's mobile app and we need to send notifications to users from API based on some events. I need some advice on how I can implement this. I am looking for a platform where I can send notifications for both IOS and Android. I recently came across Firebase and got some info that the mobile-app will send a device token to the server, then we will handle the push notification using this token. My assumption here is, I need to save this device token for all the users in a database and send the notification as necessary. Is this the best approach or are there any other good approaches for this? I am pretty sure there will a lot of solutions where I do not have to handle this myself (in database)

I was also looking into Azure Notification Hub for this, but the cons I felt here is that my UI guy (outsourced) is developing the application in React Native and I have not seen any good examples of React Native using Azure Notification Hub.

I am expecting around 1000 users for my application and I am developing my backend in ASP.NET WebAPI. Mostly I will have 2 types of notification

- Push notification to specific user.
- Push Notification regarding new installations to all the users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, according to my experience the best way and the easiest way is using firebase. You will have a lots of option there. In fact according to their comment, whether you're a beginner, intermediate or advanced React Native developer you can be up and running with React Native Firebase in no time.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-firebase

For more information and adding a project:

https://rnfirebase.io

Firebase getting start:
https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase-starter

How does it work?

Firebase Cloud Messaging architecture diagram
An FCM implementation includes two main components for sending and receiving:

A trusted environment such as Cloud Functions for Firebase or an app server on which to build, target, and send messages.
An iOS, Android, or web (JavaScript) client app that receives messages.
You can send messages via the Admin SDK or the HTTP and XMPP APIs. For testing or for sending marketing or engagement messages with powerful built-in targeting and analytics, you can also use the Notifications composer.

[image]

last comment copy-right: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/

Comment: So, I believe this will send me a device token and the best approach is to handle this in my database to send notification to specific users?

Comment: @Joe89: In fact, you will have a panel inside your account at https://firebase.google.com that using that you can send any thing that you want to special user or special device type(iOS-android) or all the users. You also can call an API to execute push notification instead of using the panel. I hope I could help :)

Comment: You have any idea regarding the pricing for FCM? I see it is free but not sure why they want to give this as free?

Comment: @Joe89: Fortunately according to their clams it should be free. Also for us it is free till now. :) Please check it here: https://firebase.google.com/pricing/?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIw-j-sLiz4AIVmRrTCh0l4Q_xEAAYASABEgLvvPD_BwE